# GWT urls change when deployed to tomcat

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat

Simple question, maybe someone knows:

In GWT devmode, my urls look like this: `http://myserver/myapp/myservice`
When I run 'ant war' and deploy that war on tomcat, they mysteriously change to: `http://myserver/myapp/myapp/myservice`

Everything still works, but obviously the URLs are uglier. I'd like to just keep the URLs used in devmode. Any info is appreciated, thanks.

-tjw

Comment: what is the folder structure inside tomcat from /webapps/?

Comment: post your `servlet mappings` from your `web.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've got a solution for this. So many people are having this problem all over the net, I decided to answer my own question. The key is to use `@RemoteServiceRelativePath` in your `RemoteService` interface file. For example, to solve my original problem, I would annotate my `RemoteService` interface like this:

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("../myservice")
```

This way, whatever path is in front of the service's URL is irrelevant. Now in the `web.xml`, instead of using `/myapp/myservice` as the `url-pattern`, I just use `/myservice`. Now it works in both GWT's devmode and in Tomcat with no further modification needed.

Comment: You probably don't even need the @RemoteServiceRelativePath annotation.  It was probably fixed just by changing the url-pattern in your web.xml.  I'm guessing your war was named myapp.war.  When you deploy to tomcat, the default is to use the war name as it's root path.  Therefore  the first /myapp you were seeing was actually telling tomcat to send the request to your war.

Answer (score 1):

Deploy the web service as ROOT.war, not as myapp.war, because the first 'myapp' is the web application context path, and 'myapp/myservice' is the path inside the web application.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without deploying under root?

Comment: Yes. We are using our custom web server and running GWT devmode with the -noserver switch. This way, it all depends on your web server configuration.

Comment: Oops, should have read this before adding a comment above.  This is indeed the reason for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change your mappings in your `web.xml` to all start with `/` instead of `/myapp/` and deploy your application as `myapp.war` or deploy the war as `Root.war`